# how to specify that two queries can be run in parallel in plpgsql

Tags: postgresql

Is there a way of controlling asynchronous flow within postgres using plpgsql?

I know there are parallel queries so can the statements also be parallelised?

```sql
DECLARE
JSONB res1
JSONB res2
BEGIN
res1 := select * ... 
res2 := func2();

return func3(res1, res2)
END
```

I'd like to be able to specify that the calls for `res1` and `res2` can be run in parallel within postgres itself.

Comment: This depends on the programming language you are using. But essentially you need to open up two connections from your application - one for each query

Comment: Postgres will run queries in parallel just fine. It's your programming language which must be able to execute queries and fetch results in parallel.

Comment: okay... the question was a little bit unclear. I need to to run inside of postgres.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To run two SQL statements in parallel, you need two database connections.

Comment: The answer remains the same - you cannot do that.